# for same ids from two data sets finding with specific time difference

Tags: r

df1 (having unique ids)

| id | date1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/26/2022 |
| 2 | 9/15/2021 |
| 3 | 12/22/2021 |
| 5 | 1/19/2022 |
| 6 | 1/11/2022 |

df2 (having duplicate ids)

| id | date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 5/10/2022 |
| 3 | 5/26/2022 |
| 4 | 11/28/2020 |
| 4 | 12/18/2021 |
| 5 | 1/19/2022 |
| 6 | 12/11/2021 |
| 6 | 1/13/2022 |
| 6 | 2/01/2022 |
| 7 | 12/08/2020 |
| 8 | 12/08/2020 |

I want the following form;
the date difference should be <21 days but need to select the closest date (yes=1, no=0).

| id | date1 | date2 | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 12/22/2021 | 5/10/2022 | 0 |
| 5 | 1/19/2022 | 1/19/2022 | 1 |
| 6 | 1/11/2022 | 1/13/2022 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
 mutate(date1 = mdy(date1)) %>% 
 inner_join(df2 %>%
    mutate(date2 = mdy(date2)), by = join_by(id, 
    closest(date1 <= date2))) %>% 
  mutate(new_col = +((date2 - date1) < 21))
```

-output

```
   id      date1      date2 new_col
1  3 2021-12-22 2022-05-10       0
2  5 2022-01-19 2022-01-19       1
3  6 2022-01-11 2022-01-13       1
```

-output

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L), date1 = c("5/26/2022", 
"9/15/2021", "12/22/2021", "1/19/2022", "1/11/2022")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L), 
    date2 = c("5/10/2022", "5/26/2022", "11/28/2020", "12/18/2021", 
    "1/19/2022", "12/11/2021", "1/13/2022", "2/01/2022", "12/08/2020", 
    "12/08/2020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Comment: Facing the following error:
Error in UseMethod("inner_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "character". 
Ids are already in "integer" and dates are in date format.

Comment: @Hasan I showed a reproducible example with the data (which is working fine for me).  Also, specified the version of `dplyr` which should be used

Comment: I have used dplyr. 
It was asking to use multiple = "all". I have tried multiple ="all" which giving df with NA and no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character". 
Please advice.

`df1 %>% 
  mutate(date1 = mdy(date1)) %>% multiple = "all" %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>%
               mutate(date2 = mdy(date2)), by = join_by(id, 
                                                        closest(date1 <= date2))) %>% 
  mutate(new_col = +((date2 - date1) < 21))`

Comment: @Hasan Is the error based on the data I showed in the. post or a different data.  if it is different data, you may need to show the structure of data with `dput(yourdata)`